# responsive image bootstrap thumbnail

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I'm trying to create a bootstrap gallery with the thumbnail component. I pulled the code directly from getboostrap.

When viewing the page at full size everything looks fine. However, when I resize the screen to make it smaller the images don't adjust to fit inside of the thumbnail box. What I was hoping to do is have an image that adjusts in size based on how wide the thumbnail box is.

Instead the thumbnail box ends up being substantially wider than the image itself, especially on medium sized screens. The images I'm using for my source images are more than large enough to take up the entire space within the thumbnail.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: Please Post Your Codes here